# What mounting adapter do I need for this shotgun mic?

Tags: boom-pole

I am looking at [this shotgun mic](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/238826-REG/Azden_SGM_1X_SGM_1X_Shotgun_Mic.html) and I am making a boom pole from [this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83d3qLHaAN4) I know there is a mic adapter and shock mount in that video, but since the shotgun mic comes with a shock mount, what mounting adapter/connector do I need for the shotgun mic to connect to the boom pole?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a budget, and if you are making your own boom pole - I'm assuming you are, you could try this...
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/621574-REG/Interfit_STR116_STR116_Hot_Shoe.html

I'd gaff tape it for insurance.

Comment: Yes, I am making my own boom pole. I could use a hot shoe, but I'd rather not as it's not as good quality audio (I also have two cameras)